# Synchronising data between a webSQL database and a MySQL database

Tags: synchronization, web-sql, data-synchronization

In an application I am writing, it is necessary for me to keep a two way synchronisation between the local webSQL database and the remote MySQL database.

I have come across libraries like Persistencejs and Impel.inTouch, Persistencejs seems to have a plugin for what I want, but from what I gather it only synchronises on a per-object granularity, and thus the database could become inconsistent?

The server-side example isn't very clear either, and it's confusing on whether Persistencejs will or will not synchronise the database schema as well.

Impel.inTouch on the other hand seems to only focus on keeping the database schema's synchronised, and not the data.

I am looking for a simple way to synchronise a set of tables between a remote MySQL database and a local WebSQL database. The frameworks I already have included are jQuery and jQuery mobile.

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to assume that you have control of the domain that is creating the local Web SQL database.  Otherwise, you don't have access to the local database.

There might be different ways, but the one way I can think of is to deploy a Rails app on domain that has a map between the local database tables and Rails models (these models need to be realized on the server using MySql).  Create a route (say foo.com/sync) to inspect each record and model and sync according to some algorithm (last modified, for example).